# Apple Watch Simulator completely fails to start or load app with message "Waiting to attach"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, ios-simulator, apple-watch

The Apple Watch Simulator always fails to load my WatchKit App. The entire process has always been quite flaky, but for a reason I can't figure out, the Watch simply hangs on a black screen without loading anything. No home screen, no app, no spinner, no time or date.

I've tried:

1. All combinations of clean/launch/stop/quit/reload/restart/etc..
2. Resetting simulator content and settings
3. Different versions of the sim, phone, iOS, etc
4. Recreating the scheme
5. Checking the code hasn't been trashed by accident, and the "Startup Interface"
6. Going to the WatchKitSettings (Apple Watch) app on the sim:- it's empty.

All I see is the title (e.g. Apple Watch 42mm); the rest of the screen is black.

The only thing that's changed in the project recently is the addition of Launch Files and Icon files. But the WatchKit target does not have any of these.
It's like there's a problem somewhere down in the depths of the WatchKit installation/xCode debugger. I often get the message "Waiting to attach" in the debug navigator (sometimes repeated multiple times), sometimes the message "No Debug Session" remains.

Does anyone please have any helpful tips or experience with a similar situation that might get me building again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a combination of:

- a problem with the project's (Apple Watch, iOS App & WatchkitExtension) Bundle Identifier

  - Check your bundle IDs are all correct and the parts that need to match match
  - Check your provisioning profiles include the ID, are set to the correct team and match throughout the project's targets
- A problem with the signing of the WatchkitBundle

  - Due in parts to the issues noted above, but also related to the "Skip Install" 'Build Setting' of the Watchkit App

Usual steps of reset simulator, restart xcode and machine. XCode 7 is a poor effort so far.